# Visual Web Developer 2010 - no intellisense and compiler doesn't pick up syntax errors

Tags: visual-web-developer

I've just installed Visual Web Developer Express 2010, and I'm trying to write & compile some basic VB code (to do with Object Data Sources).

However, when I write my class (which is sitting in APP_Code folder), I find that :

1) I dont get any intellisense / code completion happening, and that
2) More of a problem, the compiler doesn't pick up coding syntax errors, and gives a successful build no matter what I write in the class file.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks,
Bazza

Answer (score 0):

The "Build Action" in the properties of the file needs to be set to "Compile" - my guess is that it is something else now, causing the compiler to ignore the file.